# Quick way to Upper every value in xml?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I have the following xml:

```
<Item>
  <Platform>itunes</Platform>
  <PlatformID>102224185</PlatformID>
  <Info>
    <LanguageOfMetadata>EN</LanguageOfMetadata>
    <Name>Commander In Chief</Name>
    <Studio>abc</Studio>
  </Info>
  <Type>TVSeries</Type>
</Item>
```

What would be the quickest way to `UPPER` all the values? For example:

```
<Item>
  <Platform>ITUNES</Platform>
  <PlatformID>102224185</PlatformID>
  <Info>
    <LanguageOfMetadata>EN</LanguageOfMetadata>
    <Name>COMMANDER IN CHIEF</Name>
    <Studio>ABC</Studio>
  </Info>
  <Type>TVSERIES</Type>
</Item>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all elements and call `upper()` on each element's text:

```
import lxml.etree as ET

data = """<Item>
  <Platform>itunes</Platform>
  <PlatformID>102224185</PlatformID>
  <Info>
    <LanguageOfMetadata>EN</LanguageOfMetadata>
    <Name>Commander In Chief</Name>
    <Studio>abc</Studio>
  </Info>
  <Type>TVSeries</Type>
</Item>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(data)
for elm in root.xpath("//*"):  # //* would find all elements recursively
    elm.text = elm.text.upper()

print(ET.tostring(root))
```

Prints:

```
<Item>
  <Platform>ITUNES</Platform>
  <PlatformID>102224185</PlatformID>
  <Info>
    <LanguageOfMetadata>EN</LanguageOfMetadata>
    <Name>COMMANDER IN CHIEF</Name>
    <Studio>ABC</Studio>
  </Info>
  <Type>TVSERIES</Type>
</Item>
```

This though does not cover cases when you, for example, have a tail of an element - e.g. have `<Studio>ABC</Studio>test` instead of just `<Studio>ABC</Studio>`. To support that as well, put the following under the for loop as well:

```
elm.tail = elm.tail.upper() if elm.tail else None
```

Comment: thank you. For whatever reason, I had to add the following `if` statement or else I would run into an error:         `for elm in root.xpath("//*"):  
            if elm.text:
                elm.text = elm.text.upper()`

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way to upper everything, though note that this will include the tags as well:

```
node = etree.fromstring(etree.tostring(item).upper())
print etree.tostring(node, pretty_print=True)

<ITEM>
  <PLATFORM>ITUNES</PLATFORM>
  <PLATFORMID>102224185</PLATFORMID>
  <INFO>
    <LANGUAGEOFMETADATA>EN</LANGUAGEOFMETADATA>
    <NAME>COMMANDER IN CHIEF</NAME>
    <STUDIO>ABC</STUDIO>
  </INFO>
  <TYPE>TVSERIES</TYPE>
</ITEM>
```

Comment: This is how you upper any string, so that seems obvious, and I don't know if it answers your own question.

Comment: @cricket_007 right, I was just showing basically how to get the upper stringed back into the node.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you can parse the XML file you can just rewrite the contents using the `.upper()` function that is built into python for strings. You can call it like that:
`"mystring".upper()`.

Comment: Question wanted to upper just the items, not the tags as well.

Comment: @cricket_007 I did mention that I assumed OP could parse the XML and extract the contents. Never did I say that he/she should `upper()` everything

Comment: Ah, I understand what you are saying, still isn't quite a complete answer, though

Comment: I know, alexce's answer is better. But still I wanted to make myself clear.